# Orthogonal bases and Gram–Schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, gram-schmidt

What is the closest function $a \cos(x) + b \sin(x)$ to the function $ f(x) = \sin(2x)$ on the interval from $-\pi$ to $\pi$? What is the closest straight line $c + dx$?

This is a problem in linear algebra from the book “Linear Algebra and its applications” by Gilbert Strang. The problem is in chapter 3, section “Orthogonal bases and Gram-Schmidt”.
I am not able to model this into vectors so that I can project it onto another vector to get the “closest function”.
Any hints on how to look at these as vectors would help me.

Comment: What is your normed space?

Comment: Real number space, with Euclidean distance metric? 
Nothing else is given in the question other than what I have written above.

Comment: About what “closest” means - I do not exactly know what it is here, given the objects being functions. I guess it could mean the minimum of the two functions by least squares way ( I am not sure), asking for what it means here is valid and necessary. Also, my thinking is majorly occupied by the idea of projecting a vector on a line perpendicularly to get the closest point on the line to the tip of the vector (a point). But this has to be generalised to functions here which I am not able to model it, because that the central idea going on in this section.

Comment: I assume you have to look at the $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$ space. The norm is generated by an inner-product and orthogonality has meaning in this space. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space).